# Laravel customise logic for login/password reset

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I need to customise the logic for Laravel's authentication. I found a solution on SO, by overriding the `credentials` method in the `LoginController` like so:

`return ['email' => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'status_id' => $whatever];`

But now I discovered an issue where a user can still reset their password and then they get signed in automatically. So how can I disable password resets for users who should not be allowed to sign in?

Answer (score 0):

There is a method on the `ResetsPasswords` trait called `resetPassword()`

Override this in your `Auth/ResetPasswordController` and replace the line

```
$this->guard()->login($user);
```

with whatever functionality you want to achieve after the password reset.

If you want to prevent a disabled user from resetting their password, use a middleware to check if the account is disabled before continuing with the password reset.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to not let it get that far. If a user's account is disabled, they should not be able to change their password and then discover their account is disabled. I guess I can look into overriding the `sendResetLinkEmail` of the `SendsPasswordResetEmails` trait.

Comment: Edited my answer, TL;DR: use middleware.

Comment: Of course, that makes a lot of sense. Initially I was hesitant to add a query to the statuses table for every page load, but the query can be cached :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new column to your user table `isbanned` that excepts only boolean value. And check further of this column value of a user that requests for reset password. If the value is `TRUE`, don't give the reset link, otherwise, give it.
Below you can see this example:

`if (Auth::attempt(array('phone' => $request->input('phone'), 'password' => $request->input('password'), 'isactive' => '1', 'isbannes' => '0'), $remember)){
  // your logic
}`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: How does this address the issue of password resets still being able to log a user in?